# How To Transfer File Between 2 PSDrives

Tags: powershell

I created two PSDrives on my client computer PowerShell session to two different Remote Servers.

```
New-PSDrive -Name DllFrom -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\WPDHSFMSLxx\adap\Database\Install\KareAssistTest\HIDn"

New-PSDrive -Name DllTo -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\WTDHSAPPLxx\d\ServerDLLDev"
```

I can `dir` either one and contents are displayed.

I can't copy a text file between these 2 drives using `Copy-Item`:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Copy-Item DllFrom/HelloWorld.txt DllTo/HelloWorld.txt
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllFrom\HelloWorld.txt' because it does
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item DllFrom/HelloWorld.txt DllTo/HelloWorld.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\syst...\HelloWorld.txt:String) [
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I changed the location to the DLLFrom drive and tried it.

```
Set-Location DllFrom:
PS DllFrom:\>Copy-Item HelloWorld.txt DllTo
```

and

```
PS DllFrom:\> Copy-Item \\WPDHSFMSL03\adap\Database\Install\KareAssistTest\HIDn\HelloWorld.txt DllTo
```

Nothing happened, command line refreshed, but no file showed up.

Comment: DllFrom and DllTo are drives, and need a colon in their name.  Try referring to them as DllFrom:\HellowWorld.txt and DllTo:\HelloWorld.txt

Comment: Ok. That worked. I had to give permissions to the "d" share but then it worked. Please make this an answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ensure that ServerDLLDev exists and is a directory, not a file...  That's just one possible reason - of many - for the error.

Comment: Don't forget to clean-up those extraneous files named "DllTo" :)

Comment: No. No Extraneous files because the share hadn't been given the permissions yet.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DllFrom and DllTo are drives, and need a colon in their name when you refer to them. You create them with a `-Name` without the colon, but later use it when using the drive, just like a single letter drive `C:` or other providers like `HKCU:`

Try: `Copy-Item DllFrom:/HelloWorld.txt DllTo:/HelloWorld.txt`

There is more [overview on PSDrives at 4sysops](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-psdrive-in-practice). From the linked page:

> Remember that the PSDrive name does not include the colon (:) but you need to include it when using the drive to set location.

When you did `Copy-Item HelloWorld.txt DllTo`, you'll find a copy of HellowWorld.txt in your current directory named "DllTo"

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It even works from client where PS session is running without using a "Set-Location DllFrom:".

Comment: Using `(Get-PSProvider -PSProvider FileSystem).Drives` will also show you the drives you have made in this manner